# how to get eclipse neon to work with maven 2

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

New Eclipse (neon) not working with Maven 2. I get "Not applicable" message. (see screenshot)

**Note**: Updating the projects to work with maven 3 is not an option in the meanwhile, because it will take a lot of time. (we heavily depend on maven 2 in all build lifecycles)[image]

Comment: Sorry [Maven 2 is End Of Life](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html) and the support in Eclipse is Maven 3.X. Apart from that Upgrade to Maven 3 shouldn't be that hard except you are using reporting...

Comment: What exactly will take a lot of time to upgrade?